# React hooks state undefined on handle function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a simple quiz with persisting response state and i am currently stuck trying to figure out why responseState is undefined in my handleAnswerClick function, this function is triggered much later if at all per click. By then the States should all be set.

```
const Question: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {
const [responseState, setResponseState] = useState([]);
const [question, setQuestion] = useState<IStateProps>(props.id);
const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);
const [choice, setChoice] = useState();

const initialResponseState = () => {
    const data = {
        duration: '00:01:00',
        examTakerProgress: 1,
        question: props.id,
        answer: '1',
    }
    axios.post(`${host}/api/responseState/`, data)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Created the initial Response State');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
}

const getData = async () => {
    await axios.all([
        axios.get(`${host}/api/question/${question}`),
        axios.get(`${host}/api/responseState/examTakerProgress/1/question/${props.id}`)
    ])
        .then(axios.spread((questionData, responseData) => {
            if (!responseData.data.length > 0) {
                initialResponseState();
            }
            setResponseState(responseData.data);
            setQuestion(questionData.data);
            setAnswers(questionData.data.answers);
            setChoice(responseData.data.length > 0 ? responseData.data[0].answer : '');
            setTimeout(() => {
                props.toggleLoading();
            }, 50);

        }))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
};

useEffect(() => {
    getData()
}, [])


const handleAnswerClick = async (number: number) => {
    setChoice(number);
    const data = {
        duration: '00:01:00',
        examTakerProgress: 1,
        question: props.id,
        answer: number,
    }
    await axios.put(`${host}/api/responseState/${responseState[0].id}/`, data)
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            console.log('choice changed to :' + number);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
}

if (props.loading) {
    return <Loader/>
}

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <h3>{question.label}</h3>
        <p className='mb-3'>{question.description}</p>
        <ListGroup as="ul">
            {answers.map((answer, index) => {
                    if (answer.id === choice) {
                        return <ListGroup.Item key={answer.id} action active> <Answer key={index}
                                                                                      answer={answer}/></ListGroup.Item>

                    } else {
                        return <ListGroup.Item key={answer.id} action onClick={() => {
                            handleAnswerClick(answer.id)
                        }}><Answer key={index}
                                   answer={answer}/></ListGroup.Item>
                    }
                }
            )}
        </ListGroup>
    </React.Fragment>
)};
```

Can someone explain me the reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this line

`const [responseState, setResponseState] = useState({});`,

the `responseState` is an object.

but in the `handleAnswerClick` function you are using it as an array `${responseState[0].id}`.

Note that this actually works if the object has a `0` key but since you're getting undefined that is not the case.

Comment: Ah yeah i was testing a theory an forgot to change it back, but the problem is that my handleClick is never getting the data which to me is weird since the data is being set waayyy before..
Error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: Well, that just means that data is not being properly set.

Answer (score 1):

## Reasons why `responseState` is `undefined`.

1. The most obvious is that you set `responseState` to undefined

The only place you call `setResponseState` is in `getData` where you have `setResponseState(responseData.data);`, so please check if `responseData.data` isn't undefined.

2. You never get to call `setResponseState` and the initial state is an object but you try to get `responseState[0].id`

I'm not sure what data type you are handling, but if you defined `const [responseState, setResponseState] = useState({});` with the default value of `useState` as `{}` and then try to access `responseState[0].id`, there is two things happening.

Either you have an object with number keys or you have an array, but if you have an array, you should declare the initial value as an array.

But this isn't the problem, the problem is that you might never get to the part where you call `setResponseState(responseData.data);` and then you will have `responseState` to be `{}` and when trying to do `responseState[0]` it will be `undefined`, and when calling `responseState[0].id` you will get an error saying that you cannot read `id` of `undefined`.

## Ways to fix this

1. Debug your code, make sure that the api call returns what you are expecting and `setResponseState(responseData.data);` is called.
2. Check if `responseState[0]` exists before try to access `responseState[0].id`

I would be able to help more, but you didn't add more information, so it's hard to help, but above is what I think it's the problem

Comment: I am getting the data i want the problem is that for some reason HandleAnswerClick is not getting the ResponseState state which is weird since this state is being set much before the handleClick is triggered. I do not understand why it does not exist by the time the function is triggered

error:
Question.tsx:101 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: @Steytz Please add an console.log before the place where the error happens and show me what you see. And where exactly that erro happens? Inside `handleAsnwerClick` but in what line?

Comment: console.log(responseState); logs [] but i do not understand why, by the time this function is even triggered the state should be long set. Ps: as soon as i change question and come back to the same one it works no problem since the state is then already set.

Answer (score 0):

Basically i am creating a responseState when a question loads for the first time, if a question is afterwards reloaded the State is already there since it is persisted. This means i also have to make sure to call setResponseState for the first case where the ResponseState still does not exist.

```
const initialResponseState = () => {
const data = {
    duration: '00:01:00',
    examTakerProgress: 1,
    question: props.id,
    answer: '1',
}
axios.post(`${host}/api/responseState/`, data)
    .then(() => {
            setResponseState(res.data)
        console.log('Created the initial Response State');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })}
```